# Excel macro works in Debug but not in full run

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

So I have a macro that is designed to insert 4 header rows for each page break in the sheet's print area. It will insert the correct header rows for every page break when I run through it step by step in debug mode, however when it is running by itself it seems to be skipping parts. I have added Sleeps and Debug.Prints in order to figure out where it is going wrong and I still cannot figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
Sub InsertRowPageBreak()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pb As Variant
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim OffSet As Integer
    Dim InsertRow As Integer

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    WS.Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    For Each pb In WS.HPageBreaks
        Debug.Print "Iteration: " & i
        i = i + 1

        Row = pb.Location.Row
        Range("A" & Row).Select
        Debug.Print "Page Break at Row: " & Row

        If (Range("A" & Row - 2).Value Like "*Date*") Then
            InsertRow = Row - 4
            Range("A" & InsertRow).Select
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
            Debug.Print "Inserting Page Break @ Row: " & InsertRow
        Else
            Sleep 150
            InsertRow = Row - 1
            Debug.Print "Inserting Row " & InsertRow
            If (Range("D" & InsertRow).Value Like "*Compliment*") Then
                Sleep 150
                Sheets(2).Activate
                Rows("1:4").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets(1).Activate
                Range("A" & InsertRow).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
                Debug.Print "Inserted Header 1"
            ElseIf (Range("D" & InsertRow).Value Like "*Complaint*") Then
                Sleep 150
                Sheets(2).Activate
                Rows("5:8").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets(1).Activate
                Range("A" & InsertRow).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
                Debug.Print "Inserted Header 2"
            ElseIf (Range("D" & InsertRow).Value Like "*Question*") Then
                Sleep 150
                Sheets(2).Activate
                Rows("9:12").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets(1).Activate
                Range("A" & InsertRow).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
                Debug.Print "Inserted Header 3"
            End If
            Sleep 250
        End If
        Sleep 250
    Next pb

End Sub
```

When I run it in Debug mode the Debug.Print prints out

```
Iteration: 1
Page Break at Row: 33
Inserting Row 32
Inserted Header 1

Iteration: 2
Page Break at Row: 66
Inserting Row 65
Inserted Header 1

Iteration: 3
Page Break at Row: 94
Inserting Row 93
Inserted Header 2

Iteration: 4
Page Break at Row: 119
Inserting Row 118
Inserted Header 3
```

And when it runs by it's self

```
Iteration: 1
Page Break at Row: 33
Inserting Row 32
Inserted Header 1

Iteration: 2
Page Break at Row: 35
Inserting Row 34

Iteration: 3
Page Break at Row: 92
Inserting Row 91
Inserted Header 2

Iteration: 4
Page Break at Row: 94
Inserting Row 93
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After inserting a `Pagebreak` Excel needs to repaginate in order to update the `HPageBreaks` collection.

In order to allow Excel to do this while the code is running, use `DoEvents` in place of your `Sleep`'s

Comment: I have spent Hours trying to figure out how to get this done and all that it took was that little piece of code. Wow. THANK YOU!!! That is not a piece of code I had ever used. Learn something new every day. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access Excel at the moment, so I can't exactly answer your question, but if I were you, I would do a few things different because right now your code look very error-prone.

First off, any time you add or remove rows to a sheet via a loop, you should have it step backwards. For example:

```
dim i as integer

for i = mySheet.usedrange.rows.count to 1 step -1

  'Put your code here

next i
```

In this case, you would have to do something like loop through the pagebreaks first and identify the row numbers then loop through the row number in reverse order, but it might help.

Secondly, assign any worksheets you will be using to a variable, and reference those instead of calling the activate method. I used to use `activate` too, but have since learned it is a rookie mistake and I honestly can't remember why I used it in the first place. For instance, instead of doing this:

```
Sheets(2).Activate
Rows("1:4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A" & InsertRow).Select
```

Do something like this:

```
dim myBook as workbook, a as worksheet, b as worksheet

set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
set a = myBook.Sheets(1)
set b = myBook.Sheets(2)

b.rows("1:4").Select
Selection.Copy
a.Range("A" & InsertRow).Select
```

Like I said, I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, and I would have put it in a comment if it wasn't so long, but I really think this will greatly reduce errors in the future and help with your overall [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). 
If I had Excel right now I could do more. Sorry I can't be more help, but good luck!

Comment: -1 good advice to avoid `Activate` but very bad advice on how to avoid it!

Comment: Thanks for the post. The majority of my loops that do inserts I do go from the bottom up. Howeever, since I am inserting 4 new rows each time at the page breaks I have to go top down otherwise the rows i already inserted might not be at a page break by the time it finished.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Okay I'm interested now. What do you mean?

Comment: @Lopsided Not only should you avoid `Activate`, you should avoid `Select` too. And in the code fragment you posted if `b` is not the `Activesheet` then `b.rows("1:4").Select` will fail

Comment: Ooh yeah I see what you mean. No I didn't have excel so I just copy/pasted his code and changed the way I would reference sheets. I thought you meant there was a better way to avoid activate.

Comment: @Lopsided: An interesting link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select